# Private packages: are debug files necessary to compile a project in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, vcpkg

I'm trying to create a package (from local binaries) that can be installed using vcpkg. In vcpkg the file hierarchy for installed packages is:

```
package
   |- bin
   |- include
   |- lib
   |- debug
        |- bin
        |- lib
```

In case that the package doesn't have any debug binaries, do I have to copy the release binaries to the debug folder in order to use them or does vcpkg fall automatically back to the release binaries?

Comment: A concrete example of such a library [is provided](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/packaging-zlib/), give it a spin on yours.

Comment: @HansPassant I've read the example but I'm still not sure. In the ffmpeg package it looks like the binaries are the same for release and debug. My packages don't have any debug binaries or debug symbols. Removing the copy to debug causes the installation to fail so I guess I have to keep it in.